# powershell convert-tojson not giving optimal results

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell question, I need to convert this piece of code to Json

```
$Dimensions = @(
    @{
        name  = 'num_vm'
        value = '100'
    },
    @{
        name  = 'days'
        value = '10'
    },
    @{
        name  = 'months'
        value = '12'
    }
)

For ($i=0;$i -lt $Dimensions.length;$i++)
{
 $bodymessage = @{'resourceId' = $resourceUsageId; 'quantity' = "$Dimensions[$i].value"; 'dimension' = "$Dimensions[$i].name"; 'effectiveStartTime' = $lastHourMinusFiveMinutes; 'planId' = 'plan_meter' }
    $body += @{
          request = 
            @($bodymessage)} `
              |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
  
                       
   

}

$body
```

what I'm hoping, is it can dynamically create the JSON output according to the dimension input,
but the result I got is this

```
{
    "request":  [
                    {
                        "resourceId":  null,
                        "quantity":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[0].value",
                        "planId":  "plan_meter",
                        "dimension":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[0].name",
                        "effectiveStartTime":  null
                    }
                ]
}{
    "request":  [
                    {
                        "resourceId":  null,
                        "quantity":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[1].value",
                        "planId":  "plan_meter",
                        "dimension":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[1].name",
                        "effectiveStartTime":  null
                    }
                ]
}{
    "request":  [
                    {
                        "resourceId":  null,
                        "quantity":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[2].value",
                        "planId":  "plan_meter",
                        "dimension":  "System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[2].name",
                        "effectiveStartTime":  null
                    }
                ]
}
```

how can i get rid of System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable System.Collections.Hashtable[0].value?
and displaying with real value?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"$Dimensions[$i].value"` and `"$Dimensions[$i].name"`. Also adding to an array with `+=` is wasteful as the entire array needs to be recreated in memory each time. Remove `$body += ` and instead capture with `$body = for ($i=0; $i -lt $Dimensions.Count; $i++) {..}`

Comment: To add to Theo's helpful comment and  Bender the Greatest's helpful answer: As for how `"$Dimensions[$i].value"` is expanded (interpolated): [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) explains the rules of interpolation in PowerShell's _expandable strings_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is how you're assigning the hashtable element values within a string. Fix it by removing the quotes like so (formatted multiline for readability):

```
$bodymessage = @{
  resourceId = $resourceUsageId;
  quantity = $Dimensions[$i].value; # Removed the quotes here
  dimension = $Dimensions[$i].name; # Removed the quotes here
  effectiveStartTime = $lastHourMinusFiveMinutes;
  planId = 'plan_meter';
}
```

> **Note:** I've also removed the single-quotes `'` around the key names since they are not needed in this context. You only need to quote key names if non-alphanumeric characters are part of the key name, and you are assigning the key name as a literal string.

---

### Why did this happen?

This happens because of how variable expansion within strings works. The following string you originally had:

```
"$Dimensions[$i].value"
```

will see `$Dimensions` get expanded (its `ToString()` function is implicitly called), not `$Dimensions[$i].value`. This is because variable parsing starts at the dollar-sign `$` and stops at the first character which can't normally be part of a variable name. This will be most special characters, excepting the colon `:`.

---

However, if you are trying to force a string value (and you may not be), you can perform a sub-expression within the string to evaluate the members of an object, including array-accessors and object properties. You can also perform more complex expressions as well, but for your case below you could leave the quotes and use `$()` to get the result you want:

```
"$($Dimensions[$i].value)"
```

The `$()` tells the parser to "run this expression and put the result into the string". Again, whatever object is returned will implicitly have `ToString()` run on it when it gets inserted into the final string, so whatever output `$Dimensions[$i].value.ToString()` produces will be your string value.

Comment: this explanation is so detailed, thanks so much!